# geom_text overwrites on facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problem that my geom_text is written multiple times on the same facet instead of being written once in every facet.  Here is my code:

```
plot  <- ggplot(dt.m, aes(IsomiR,value, fill=MetIso, group=MetIso))   +
  geom_boxplot(width=1,position=position_dodge(1)) +facet_wrap(~IsomiR2,scales="free",ncol=5) +  
  theme_bw(base_size=8) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(y="cpm (log2)", x="") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Met") +
  geom_text(data=Pval_Met_Iso, aes(label=paste("p=",pval)), x=-Inf, y=Inf,hjust = -.35,vjust=1.5, colour="black", inherit.aes=FALSE, parse=FALSE, size=2)
```

[image]

```
> head(Pval_Met_Iso)
    miRNASub    adj.P.Val  pval
1  let-7b-3p 3.863568e-02 0.039
2  let-7b-5p 4.834748e-02 0.048
3  let-7d-3p 1.692911e-02 0.017
4 miR-101-3p 4.462711e-02 0.045
5 miR-10a-5p 1.223826e-06 0.000
6   miR-1246 1.346736e-03 0.001


> head(dt.m)
                                          IsomiR      logFC   AveExpr         t      P.Value    adj.P.Val         B variable     value
1    hsa-let-7b-3p CTATACAACCTACTGCCTTCC 0 0 0 c -0.7545800  4.826754 -2.956565 4.296011e-03 0.0444659234 -2.229074     1_JH  4.903609
2 hsa-let-7b-5p TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGC 0 I-C 0 tt  0.7535109  9.597895  3.373377 1.239255e-03 0.0185703310 -1.302851     1_JH  9.862578
3    hsa-let-7b-5p TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGT 0 0 0 t  0.6389140 14.225179  3.103446 2.803606e-03 0.0335097674 -2.109743     1_JH 14.821167
4    hsa-let-7d-3p CTATACGACCTGCTGCCTTTC 0 0 0 t -0.9916318 10.196610 -5.039772 3.785400e-06 0.0001652409  4.127237     1_JH 10.092723
5     hsa-let-7d-3p TATACGACCTGCTGCCTTTC 0 0 c t -0.9646386  6.376290 -4.843742 7.900324e-06 0.0003101600  3.498511     1_JH  6.244552
6    hsa-let-7i-5p TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCT 0 0 0 gtt  0.5254452  9.011156  3.358856 1.296216e-03 0.0191382548 -1.330507     1_JH  9.738933
                                              IsomiR2         MetIso
1     hsa-let-7b-3p \n NTA: 0 \n 3'mod: c \n 5'mod: 0 Non-Metastasis
2  hsa-let-7b-5p \n NTA: I-C \n 3'mod: tt \n 5'mod: 0 Non-Metastasis
3     hsa-let-7b-5p \n NTA: 0 \n 3'mod: t \n 5'mod: 0 Non-Metastasis
4     hsa-let-7d-3p \n NTA: 0 \n 3'mod: t \n 5'mod: 0 Non-Metastasis
5     hsa-let-7d-3p \n NTA: 0 \n 3'mod: t \n 5'mod: c Non-Metastasis
6   hsa-let-7i-5p \n NTA: 0 \n 3'mod: gtt \n 5'mod: 0 Non-Metastasis
```

Comment: Can't answer without seeing `Pval_Met_Iso`.

Comment: @user2300940 It would make it easier answer if you provide a minimal subset of your input data (e.g. both `dt.m` and `Pval_Met_Iso`).  You can dump the data using `dput` and paste the results.  Try to make this a minimal subset of data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @steveb please see my edit.

Comment: @Axeman please see my edit

Comment: @user2300940 FYI, I really recommend using `dput` to provide data for questions.  It allows one to just cut / paste to load the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pval_Met_Iso` doesn't contain the variable that is used for faceting: `IsomiR2`. If you want `geom_text` to use facets, it needs to know which row of the data needs to go on which facet.

p.s. That data is a pain to load in with all those spaces etc.